# Contact Form 7 Text input size decrease

Tags: wordpress, html5-canvas

I am using contact form 7 plugin When form submitted, it checks for empty fields and print error message of both fields are required. After the message, user is redirected to the same page but text input sizes decrease. How can I retain the same width?

Comment: Have you tried setting a fixed length? Example: width: 200px;

Comment: ya i have fixed the length of text box 50%

Comment: Can you inspect the input field before the change and paste its code from CSS and after it changes?